# Up to date list of available nightly features?

Tags: rust

Where can I find an up to date list of available nightly features that I can activate?

Example:

```
#![feature(plugin_registrar, rustc_private)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Unstable Book has [a list of features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features.html), but some features are not documented there.

A complete list of features is contained [in the source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/135ccbaca86ed4b9c0efaf0cd31442eae57ffad7/src/librustc_feature/active.rs#L83-L530) (or the [current master branch](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/compiler/rustc_feature/src/active.rs)). To date, active features are:

```
declare_features! (
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-start: internal feature gates
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // no-tracking-issue-start

    /// Allows using compiler's own crates.
    (active, rustc_private, "1.0.0", Some(27812), None),

    /// Allows using the `rust-intrinsic`'s "ABI".
    (active, intrinsics, "1.0.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using `#[lang = ".."]` attribute for linking items to special compiler logic.
    (active, lang_items, "1.0.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using the `#[stable]` and `#[unstable]` attributes.
    (active, staged_api, "1.0.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using `#[allow_internal_unstable]`. This is an
    /// attribute on `macro_rules!` and can't use the attribute handling
    /// below (it has to be checked before expansion possibly makes
    /// macros disappear).
    (active, allow_internal_unstable, "1.0.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using `#[allow_internal_unsafe]`. This is an
    /// attribute on `macro_rules!` and can't use the attribute handling
    /// below (it has to be checked before expansion possibly makes
    /// macros disappear).
    (active, allow_internal_unsafe, "1.0.0", None, None),

    /// no-tracking-issue-end

    /// Allows using `#[link_name="llvm.*"]`.
    (active, link_llvm_intrinsics, "1.0.0", Some(29602), None),

    /// Allows using `rustc_*` attributes (RFC 572).
    (active, rustc_attrs, "1.0.0", Some(29642), None),

    /// Allows using the `box $expr` syntax.
    (active, box_syntax, "1.0.0", Some(49733), None),

    /// Allows using `#[main]` to replace the entrypoint `#[lang = "start"]` calls.
    (active, main, "1.0.0", Some(29634), None),

    /// Allows using `#[start]` on a function indicating that it is the program entrypoint.
    (active, start, "1.0.0", Some(29633), None),

    /// Allows using the `#[fundamental]` attribute.
    (active, fundamental, "1.0.0", Some(29635), None),

    /// Allows using the `rust-call` ABI.
    (active, unboxed_closures, "1.0.0", Some(29625), None),

    /// Allows using the `#[linkage = ".."]` attribute.
    (active, linkage, "1.0.0", Some(29603), None),

    /// Allows features specific to OIBIT (auto traits).
    (active, optin_builtin_traits, "1.0.0", Some(13231), None),

    /// Allows using `box` in patterns (RFC 469).
    (active, box_patterns, "1.0.0", Some(29641), None),

    // no-tracking-issue-start

    /// Allows using `#[prelude_import]` on glob `use` items.
    (active, prelude_import, "1.2.0", None, None),

    // no-tracking-issue-end

    // no-tracking-issue-start

    /// Allows using `#[omit_gdb_pretty_printer_section]`.
    (active, omit_gdb_pretty_printer_section, "1.5.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using the `vectorcall` ABI.
    (active, abi_vectorcall, "1.7.0", None, None),

    // no-tracking-issue-end

    /// Allows using `#[structural_match]` which indicates that a type is structurally matchable.
    (active, structural_match, "1.8.0", Some(31434), None),

    /// Allows using the `may_dangle` attribute (RFC 1327).
    (active, dropck_eyepatch, "1.10.0", Some(34761), None),

    /// Allows using the `#![panic_runtime]` attribute.
    (active, panic_runtime, "1.10.0", Some(32837), None),

    /// Allows declaring with `#![needs_panic_runtime]` that a panic runtime is needed.
    (active, needs_panic_runtime, "1.10.0", Some(32837), None),

    // no-tracking-issue-start

    /// Allows identifying the `compiler_builtins` crate.
    (active, compiler_builtins, "1.13.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using the `unadjusted` ABI; perma-unstable.
    (active, abi_unadjusted, "1.16.0", None, None),

    /// Allows identifying crates that contain sanitizer runtimes.
    (active, sanitizer_runtime, "1.17.0", None, None),

    /// Used to identify crates that contain the profiler runtime.
    (active, profiler_runtime, "1.18.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using the `thiscall` ABI.
    (active, abi_thiscall, "1.19.0", None, None),

    /// Allows using `#![needs_allocator]`, an implementation detail of `#[global_allocator]`.
    (active, allocator_internals, "1.20.0", None, None),

    /// Added for testing E0705; perma-unstable.
    (active, test_2018_feature, "1.31.0", None, Some(Edition::Edition2018)),

    // no-tracking-issue-end

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-end: internal feature gates
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-start: actual feature gates (target features)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // FIXME: Document these and merge with the list below.

    // Unstable `#[target_feature]` directives.
    (active, arm_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, aarch64_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, hexagon_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, powerpc_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, mips_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, avx512_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, mmx_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, sse4a_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, tbm_target_feature, "1.27.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, wasm_target_feature, "1.30.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, adx_target_feature, "1.32.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, cmpxchg16b_target_feature, "1.32.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, movbe_target_feature, "1.34.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, rtm_target_feature, "1.35.0", Some(44839), None),
    (active, f16c_target_feature, "1.36.0", Some(44839), None),

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-end: actual feature gates (target features)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-start: actual feature gates
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// Allows using the `#[link_args]` attribute.
    (active, link_args, "1.0.0", Some(29596), None),

    /// Allows defining identifiers beyond ASCII.
    (active, non_ascii_idents, "1.0.0", Some(55467), None),

    /// Allows using `#[plugin_registrar]` on functions.
    (active, plugin_registrar, "1.0.0", Some(29597), None),

    /// Allows using `#![plugin(myplugin)]`.
    (active, plugin, "1.0.0", Some(29597), None),

    /// Allows using `#[thread_local]` on `static` items.
    (active, thread_local, "1.0.0", Some(29594), None),

    /// Allows the use of SIMD types in functions declared in `extern` blocks.
    (active, simd_ffi, "1.0.0", Some(27731), None),

    /// Allows using non lexical lifetimes (RFC 2094).
    (active, nll, "1.0.0", Some(43234), None),

    /// Allows using slice patterns.
    (active, slice_patterns, "1.0.0", Some(62254), None),

    /// Allows the definition of `const` functions with some advanced features.
    (active, const_fn, "1.2.0", Some(57563), None),

    /// Allows associated type defaults.
    (active, associated_type_defaults, "1.2.0", Some(29661), None),

    /// Allows `#![no_core]`.
    (active, no_core, "1.3.0", Some(29639), None),

    /// Allows default type parameters to influence type inference.
    (active, default_type_parameter_fallback, "1.3.0", Some(27336), None),

    /// Allows `repr(simd)` and importing the various simd intrinsics.
    (active, repr_simd, "1.4.0", Some(27731), None),

    /// Allows `extern "platform-intrinsic" { ... }`.
    (active, platform_intrinsics, "1.4.0", Some(27731), None),

    /// Allows `#[unwind(..)]`.
    ///
    /// Permits specifying whether a function should permit unwinding or abort on unwind.
    (active, unwind_attributes, "1.4.0", Some(58760), None),

    /// Allows `#[no_debug]`.
    (active, no_debug, "1.5.0", Some(29721), None),

    /// Allows attributes on expressions and non-item statements.
    (active, stmt_expr_attributes, "1.6.0", Some(15701), None),

    /// Allows the use of type ascription in expressions.
    (active, type_ascription, "1.6.0", Some(23416), None),

    /// Allows `cfg(target_thread_local)`.
    (active, cfg_target_thread_local, "1.7.0", Some(29594), None),

    /// Allows specialization of implementations (RFC 1210).
    (active, specialization, "1.7.0", Some(31844), None),

    /// Allows using `#[naked]` on functions.
    (active, naked_functions, "1.9.0", Some(32408), None),

    /// Allows `cfg(target_has_atomic = "...")`.
    (active, cfg_target_has_atomic, "1.9.0", Some(32976), None),

    /// Allows `X..Y` patterns.
    (active, exclusive_range_pattern, "1.11.0", Some(37854), None),

    /// Allows the `!` type. Does not imply 'exhaustive_patterns' (below) any more.
    (active, never_type, "1.13.0", Some(35121), None),

    /// Allows exhaustive pattern matching on types that contain uninhabited types.
    (active, exhaustive_patterns, "1.13.0", Some(51085), None),

    /// Allows `union`s to implement `Drop`. Moreover, `union`s may now include fields
    /// that don't implement `Copy` as long as they don't have any drop glue.
    /// This is checked recursively. On encountering type variable where no progress can be made,
    /// `T: Copy` is used as a substitute for "no drop glue".
    ///
    /// NOTE: A limited form of `union U { ... }` was accepted in 1.19.0.
    (active, untagged_unions, "1.13.0", Some(55149), None),

    /// Allows `#[link(..., cfg(..))]`.
    (active, link_cfg, "1.14.0", Some(37406), None),

    /// Allows `extern "ptx-*" fn()`.
    (active, abi_ptx, "1.15.0", Some(38788), None),

    /// Allows the `#[repr(i128)]` attribute for enums.
    (active, repr128, "1.16.0", Some(35118), None),

    /// Allows `#[link(kind="static-nobundle"...)]`.
    (active, static_nobundle, "1.16.0", Some(37403), None),

    /// Allows `extern "msp430-interrupt" fn()`.
    (active, abi_msp430_interrupt, "1.16.0", Some(38487), None),

    /// Allows declarative macros 2.0 (`macro`).
    (active, decl_macro, "1.17.0", Some(39412), None),

    /// Allows `extern "x86-interrupt" fn()`.
    (active, abi_x86_interrupt, "1.17.0", Some(40180), None),

    /// Allows overlapping impls of marker traits.
    (active, overlapping_marker_traits, "1.18.0", Some(29864), None),

    /// Allows a test to fail without failing the whole suite.
    (active, allow_fail, "1.19.0", Some(46488), None),

    /// Allows unsized tuple coercion.
    (active, unsized_tuple_coercion, "1.20.0", Some(42877), None),

    /// Allows defining generators.
    (active, generators, "1.21.0", Some(43122), None),

    /// Allows `#[doc(cfg(...))]`.
    (active, doc_cfg, "1.21.0", Some(43781), None),

    /// Allows `#[doc(masked)]`.
    (active, doc_masked, "1.21.0", Some(44027), None),

    /// Allows `#[doc(spotlight)]`.
    (active, doc_spotlight, "1.22.0", Some(45040), None),

    /// Allows `#[doc(include = "some-file")]`.
    (active, external_doc, "1.22.0", Some(44732), None),

    /// Allows using `crate` as visibility modifier, synonymous with `pub(crate)`.
    (active, crate_visibility_modifier, "1.23.0", Some(53120), None),

    /// Allows defining `extern type`s.
    (active, extern_types, "1.23.0", Some(43467), None),

    /// Allows trait methods with arbitrary self types.
    (active, arbitrary_self_types, "1.23.0", Some(44874), None),

    /// Allows in-band quantification of lifetime bindings (e.g., `fn foo(x: &'a u8) -> &'a u8`).
    (active, in_band_lifetimes, "1.23.0", Some(44524), None),

    /// Allows associated types to be generic, e.g., `type Foo<T>;` (RFC 1598).
    (active, generic_associated_types, "1.23.0", Some(44265), None),

    /// Allows defining `trait X = A + B;` alias items.
    (active, trait_alias, "1.24.0", Some(41517), None),

    /// Allows infering `'static` outlives requirements (RFC 2093).
    (active, infer_static_outlives_requirements, "1.26.0", Some(54185), None),

    /// Allows accessing fields of unions inside `const` functions.
    (active, const_fn_union, "1.27.0", Some(51909), None),

    /// Allows casting raw pointers to `usize` during const eval.
    (active, const_raw_ptr_to_usize_cast, "1.27.0", Some(51910), None),

    /// Allows dereferencing raw pointers during const eval.
    (active, const_raw_ptr_deref, "1.27.0", Some(51911), None),

    /// Allows comparing raw pointers during const eval.
    (active, const_compare_raw_pointers, "1.27.0", Some(53020), None),

    /// Allows `#[doc(alias = "...")]`.
    (active, doc_alias, "1.27.0", Some(50146), None),

    /// Allows inconsistent bounds in where clauses.
    (active, trivial_bounds, "1.28.0", Some(48214), None),

    /// Allows `'a: { break 'a; }`.
    (active, label_break_value, "1.28.0", Some(48594), None),

    /// Allows using `#[doc(keyword = "...")]`.
    (active, doc_keyword, "1.28.0", Some(51315), None),

    /// Allows using `try {...}` expressions.
    (active, try_blocks, "1.29.0", Some(31436), None),

    /// Allows defining an `#[alloc_error_handler]`.
    (active, alloc_error_handler, "1.29.0", Some(51540), None),

    /// Allows using the `amdgpu-kernel` ABI.
    (active, abi_amdgpu_kernel, "1.29.0", Some(51575), None),

    /// Allows panicking during const eval (producing compile-time errors).
    (active, const_panic, "1.30.0", Some(51999), None),

    /// Allows `#[marker]` on certain traits allowing overlapping implementations.
    (active, marker_trait_attr, "1.30.0", Some(29864), None),

    /// Allows macro invocations on modules expressions and statements and
    /// procedural macros to expand to non-items.
    (active, proc_macro_hygiene, "1.30.0", Some(54727), None),

    /// Allows unsized rvalues at arguments and parameters.
    (active, unsized_locals, "1.30.0", Some(48055), None),

    /// Allows custom test frameworks with `#![test_runner]` and `#[test_case]`.
    (active, custom_test_frameworks, "1.30.0", Some(50297), None),

    /// Allows non-builtin attributes in inner attribute position.
    (active, custom_inner_attributes, "1.30.0", Some(54726), None),

    /// Allows `impl Trait` in bindings (`let`, `const`, `static`).
    (active, impl_trait_in_bindings, "1.30.0", Some(63065), None),

    /// Allows using `reason` in lint attributes and the `#[expect(lint)]` lint check.
    (active, lint_reasons, "1.31.0", Some(54503), None),

    /// Allows exhaustive integer pattern matching on `usize` and `isize`.
    (active, precise_pointer_size_matching, "1.32.0", Some(56354), None),

    /// Allows using `#[ffi_returns_twice]` on foreign functions.
    (active, ffi_returns_twice, "1.34.0", Some(58314), None),

    /// Allows const generic types (e.g. `struct Foo<const N: usize>(...);`).
    (active, const_generics, "1.34.0", Some(44580), None),

    /// Allows using `#[optimize(X)]`.
    (active, optimize_attribute, "1.34.0", Some(54882), None),

    /// Allows using C-variadics.
    (active, c_variadic, "1.34.0", Some(44930), None),

    /// Allows the user of associated type bounds.
    (active, associated_type_bounds, "1.34.0", Some(52662), None),

    /// Allows `if/while p && let q = r && ...` chains.
    (active, let_chains, "1.37.0", Some(53667), None),

    /// Allows #[repr(transparent)] on enums (RFC 2645).
    (active, transparent_enums, "1.37.0", Some(60405), None),

    /// Allows #[repr(transparent)] on unions (RFC 2645).
    (active, transparent_unions, "1.37.0", Some(60405), None),

    /// Allows explicit discriminants on non-unit enum variants.
    (active, arbitrary_enum_discriminant, "1.37.0", Some(60553), None),

    /// Allows `impl Trait` with multiple unrelated lifetimes.
    (active, member_constraints, "1.37.0", Some(61977), None),

    /// Allows `async || body` closures.
    (active, async_closure, "1.37.0", Some(62290), None),

    /// Allows `[x; N]` where `x` is a constant (RFC 2203).
    (active, const_in_array_repeat_expressions, "1.37.0", Some(49147), None),

    /// Allows `impl Trait` to be used inside type aliases (RFC 2515).
    (active, type_alias_impl_trait, "1.38.0", Some(63063), None),

    /// Allows the use of or-patterns (e.g., `0 | 1`).
    (active, or_patterns, "1.38.0", Some(54883), None),

    /// Allows the definition of `const extern fn` and `const unsafe extern fn`.
    (active, const_extern_fn, "1.40.0", Some(64926), None),

    /// Allows the use of raw-dylibs (RFC 2627).
    (active, raw_dylib, "1.40.0", Some(58713), None),

    /// Allows `#[track_caller]` to be used which provides
    /// accurate caller location reporting during panic (RFC 2091).
    (active, track_caller, "1.40.0", Some(47809), None),

    /// Allows making `dyn Trait` well-formed even if `Trait` is not object safe.
    /// In that case, `dyn Trait: Trait` does not hold. Moreover, coercions and
    /// casts in safe Rust to `dyn Trait` for such a `Trait` is also forbidden.
    (active, object_safe_for_dispatch, "1.40.0", Some(43561), None),

    /// Allows using the `efiapi` ABI.
    (active, abi_efiapi, "1.40.0", Some(65815), None),

    /// Allows `&raw const $place_expr` and `&raw mut $place_expr` expressions.
    (active, raw_ref_op, "1.41.0", Some(64490), None),

    /// Allows diverging expressions to fall back to `!` rather than `()`.
    (active, never_type_fallback, "1.41.0", Some(65992), None),

    /// Allows using the `#[register_attr]` attribute.
    (active, register_attr, "1.41.0", Some(66080), None),

    /// Allows using the `#[register_tool]` attribute.
    (active, register_tool, "1.41.0", Some(66079), None),

    /// Allows the use of `if` and `match` in constants.
    (active, const_if_match, "1.41.0", Some(49146), None),

    /// Allows the use of `#[cfg(sanitize = "option")]`; set when -Zsanitizer is used.
    (active, cfg_sanitize, "1.41.0", Some(39699), None),

    /// Allows using `&mut` in constant functions.
    (active, const_mut_refs, "1.41.0", Some(57349), None),

    /// Allows the use of `loop` and `while` in constants.
    (active, const_loop, "1.41.0", Some(52000), None),

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // feature-group-end: actual feature gates
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
);
```

Note that some of them are internal to *rustc* and not meant to be used, and that this list changes constantly.

The source also contains a list of [all features that were removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc_feature/removed.rs) or [accepted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc_feature/accepted.rs).

Comment: Is this the complete list? https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libsyntax/feature_gate.rs#L103-L320 Because I can not find `fn_traits`. `fnbox` also seems to be missing.

Comment: These are “library features”, they are declared with the [`#[unstable]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?utf8=✓&q=unstable+feature&type=Code) attribute in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

The file [`src/libsyntax/feature_gate.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libsyntax/feature_gate.rs) and the [reference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/doc/reference.md#compiler-features) only list compiler features, but not api features. For example, the feature [`rc_counts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.weak_count) is not listed.

Using this command:

```
ack -h --output '$1' 'unstable\(feature = "(\w+)"' $(ls -d * | grep -v -x test) | sort | uniq
```

on the Rust `src` dir, I got the following list:

```
alloc
alloc_jemalloc
alloc_system
arc_counts
as_unsafe_cell
binary_heap_append
binary_heap_extras
borrow_state
box_heap
btree_append
btree_range
btree_split_off
cell_extras
cell_get_mut
coerce_unsized
collection_placement
collections
collections_bound
collections_range
core_char_ext
core_float
core_intrinsics
core_panic
core_private_bignum
core_private_diy_float
core_slice_ext
core_str_ext
c_void_variant
dec2flt
deque_extras
derive_clone_copy
enumset
error_type_id
exit_status_from
filling_drop
fixed_size_array
float_extras
flt2dec
fmt_flags_align
fmt_internals
fnbox
fn_traits
get_type_id
heap_api
inclusive_range
integer_atomics
int_error_internals
io
io_error_internals
ip
ipv6_to_octets
iter_arith
libstd_io_internals
libstd_sys_internals
libstd_thread_internals
linked_list_contains
linked_list_extras
lookup_host
mpsc_select
nonzero
once_poison
oom
panic_abort
panic_unwind
pattern
peekable_is_empty
placement_in
placement_new_protocol
print
process_exec
pthread_t
rand
range_contains
raw
rc_counts
rc_would_unwrap
reflect_marker
rt
rustc_private
rustdoc
set_stdio
shared
slice_concat_ext
static_condvar
static_mutex
static_rwlock
step_by
step_trait
str_char
str_escape
str_internals
test
thread_local_internals
thread_local_state
try_from
unicode
unique
unsize
vec_deque_contains
zero_one
```

Comment: The feature `a` is in tests, you might want to exclude the `src/test` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ["The Unstable Book"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/)?

- I don't copy & paste the content here because it's constantly changing so very likely to be invalidated soon.