# Does the Rust stable standard library use unstable features?

Tags: rust

In the Rust standard library, [you can see](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/alloc/src/vec.rs#L2520-L2530) implementations like this which use const generics:

```rust
#[stable(feature = "vec_from_array", since = "1.44.0")]
impl<T, const N: usize> From<[T; N]> for Vec<T> {
    #[cfg(not(test))]
    fn from(s: [T; N]) -> Vec<T> {
        <[T]>::into_vec(box s)
    }
    #[cfg(test)]
    fn from(s: [T; N]) -> Vec<T> {
        crate::slice::into_vec(box s)
    }
}
```

When I try to do the same in my code

```rust
impl<const N: usize> From<[u8; N]> for Binary {
    fn from(source: [u8; N]) -> Self {
        // Implementation available for $N <= 32.
        // Requires https://caniuse.rs/features/vec_from_array, avaiable since Rust 1.44.0.
        Self(source.into())
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
   --> packages/std/src/binary.rs:105:12
    |
105 | impl<const N: usize> From<[u8; N]> for Binary {
    |            ^
    |
    = note: see issue #74878 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74878> for more information
```

I'm using Rust 1.47.0.

Does this mean the Rust stable standard library is compiled with unstable features?

Comment: Yes, it uses unstable features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Yes, it uses unstable features.
> — [Peter Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561067/does-the-rust-stable-standard-library-use-unstable-features#comment114157940_64561067)

For Rust 1.47.0's liballoc (where `Vec` is defined), it uses [sixty or so unstable features](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/library/alloc/src/lib.rs#L77-L137).

See also:

- [Is there a way to use unstable modules from Rust stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42048589/155423)
- [Is there any way to get unstable features on the compiler versions in stable or beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34430429/155423)
- [Up to date list of available nightly features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838688/155423)
- [What is a crate attribute and where do I add it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27454761/155423)
- [Using Rust nightly in production](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066765/155423)
- [Is it possible to compile one specific library with the nightly compiler and link it to a project that is compiled on stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62327338/155423)